# Vertical align mat-expansion-panel material component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-expansion-panel component with a mat-accordion.  The items are not vertically aligning center/middle.  I am not sure how to vertically align the content.

I've tried vertical-align: middle

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share a live page containing above component?

Comment: unfortunately site is not public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you use the 
You can use a padding in your css file 
Ex:

```
 .mat-expansion-panel-header {
  padding-top: 8px !important;
}
```

I think this help you.